# Low SpriteKit FPS can cause collisions to miss?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I am trying to make a game using SpriteKit in Swift Playgrounds on Xcode (I **have** to use playgrounds). The game runs fine but there is a problem that I cannot figure out. The code executes as expected only sometimes.

So the problem is that when collisions happen between a rectangular physics body and a circular one. Imagine circles falling from top, onto the rectangle. Sometimes the collision is detected and sometimes it isn't.

Can this happen because of the low fps on Xcode playground on mac? And I should expect it to run fine (Can't really find anything else wrong)?

Comment: It's a function of fps, relative velocity and size of colliding objects. There's more info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520014-usesprecisecollisiondetection

Comment: Adding that boolean property helped a little bit (maybe 10%) but i guess the fps is still too low to accurate detect collisions.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't having any other problems but low frame rate, my guess is that it's simply the simulator.